# comparing 2 dates with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to compare 2 dates in the following format shown below in variables **a** and **b** . I want to check if **a** is greater than **b** but the code below isnt working since its not a regular number

```
var a = "4/29/2015";
var b = "4/10/2015";

if(a > b){
alert("working");
}
```

Comment: Try using the Date constructor.

Comment: Please check : http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javadate.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Comment: some extra info about the Date object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: possible duplicate of [compare two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the strings to Date objects.

```js
var a = new Date("4/29/2015");
var b = new Date("4/10/2015");

if (a > b) {
  console.log(a + " is greater than " + b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `javascript`'s `Date` object:

```js
//2nd Argument month goes from 0(January) to 11(December)
var a = new Date(2015, 3, 29);
var b = new Date(2015, 3, 10);

if(a > b){
  alert("working");
}
```

Comment: But the OP's input dates are in string format. How does he extract the parts of the date?

Comment: Well, even date strings can be used to construct `Date` objects, I see there are other answers using the same...